# Powers gained from making pacts with devas

Tags: story-identification, manga

I'm looking for a manga in which the main character gains wind powers after meeting a girl dancing on a bridge when he is standing there in the rain. The girl was called a deity ("Deva"), and during the first chapter he faces a guy with 4 arms wielding a bat.

Comment: This story-identification question is about a manga with a character who "gains wind powers", another character who has "4 arms", and "Devas", which sounds fantastical to me. Hence, I have migrated it here.

Answer (score 3):

The manga name is *Popcorn Avatar* (2009) by Hoshino Koichiro.

From [Manga Updates](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=44704):

> One rainy night, Wada, a young teenage boy, standing near the edge of a bridge over a raging river - is on a depressing brink towards committing suicide. Suddenly, a beautiful blonde foreign girl, named Lisa, mysteriously appears. Who is this cheerful girl? And why is she dressed as a cheerleader? Wada wasn't interested and tries to ignore her, but Lisa kicks him off the bridge, and says "try flying." And to his surprise, he does. This power, where did it come from?
>
> It seems that there is a war between the gods and demons. And by fate, the result of this war is tied to Wada. Upon learning this, Wada does not look very pleased. Was this his purpose - his destiny? What will he choose? Does he even have a choice? Afterall, Lisa, the goddess cheering him on, is surprisingly his classmate.

Boy stands on the bridge and wants to jump, but then the aforementioned girls approaches him. Also, the guy they fight have 6 arms, though in some scenes it indeed looks as if he had only four.

Here are 2 links with examples of images from first chapter, so you can confirm it's this one:

[image: guy gets flying over a bridge. Girl is over enthusiastic]

[image: Six-armed guy wielding bats (not the animal bats...)]

Comment: I don't know, if there is some upvote/feedback system build in to do this, as I wasn't using StackExchange in ages, but thank you for editing and improving my answer @Jenayah :-)

Comment: You're welcome! And welcome back, then! :)